# Nest doorbell with google assistant speaker

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, nest-api, google-assist-api

I installed a nest hello and it works great overall, due to the wiring in my house, I couldn´t install the chime so, I receive the notifications on the phone, but I really wanted to add the chime and announcement feature, so I grabbed one of my raspberry pis and installed the google assistant, which is working now, however if i press the button on the doorbell, i dont hear anything on the raspberry google assistant, which I set as speaker, it does respond to the command for playing the video on the chromecast tv but doesnt chime or make any sound at all.

Does anyone know if this setup is compatible? or is a limitation from google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are not supported as part of the Google Assistant SDK. The [feature table](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features) listed in the documentation provides information on what capabilities are included.